# Oil droplet in Electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, velocity

suppose a horizontal plate capacitor. They are separated by $d=0.005 \text{m}$. In a homogeneous field, the oil droplet ($m=3\cdot 10^{-15} \text{ kg}$) sits at the bottom of the lower plate. Like a flash, you turn the voltage $U$ up such that the droplet shoots up.

The question is: How long did it take for the droplet to reach the other plate?

Sorry for the English explanation, it's a question I made up in my head; I am wondering whether I solved it correctly. So, first of all, here's the sketch:

[image]

Note that I am not a physics guy, so I am not really familiar with notation.

First of all, I tried finding the velocity at the end (when the droplet hits the upper plate).

By conservation of energy: $q\cdot E\cdot d= 1/2\cdot m\cdot v^2$ and therefore $v=\sqrt{\frac{2qEd}{m}}$ Then, I tried using $F=m\cdot a$ and $v=a\cdot t$ with $F=F_{el}-F_g$.

... is that correct?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE!Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Ah, I see and can understand. That's really unfortunate though! :(